# What is wrong with this xslt?

Tags: mysql, xml, xslt, liquibase

Data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
    <changeSet >
      ...
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet >
      ...
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">    
      <xsl:for-each select="databaseChangeLog/changeSet">       
        <top>  
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>      
        </top> 
      </xsl:for-each>   
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using `xsltproc` tool :

```
xsltproc input.xslt  input.xml
```

outputs nothing.

What is wrong with my xslt ?

**final working table.xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:db="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">    
      <xsl:for-each select="db:databaseChangeLog/db:changeSet">     
          <xsl:document  href="base/tables/{position()}_{name(*[1])}_{*[1]/@tableName}.xml">
           <databaseChangeLog 
                xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">               
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>                   
            </databaseChangeLog> 
        </xsl:document> 
      </xsl:for-each>     
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**note:** this splits the changelog (liquibase generateChangeLog output ) into its individual change 
log files

`xsltproc table.xslt liquibase.changelog.xml`

This is successfully generating one file per changeSet in log file . (My next goal is to group changesets that are on single table , but that is out of the scope of this question)

In case you are wondering what I am doing.

Liquibase migration tools generates a single change log file for existing db. I was experimenting to split that output into separate log file for each table/object (specifically mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace is missing in the stylesheet.
This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:db="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">    
      <xsl:for-each select="db:databaseChangeLog/db:changeSet">       
        <top>  
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>      
        </top> 
      </xsl:for-each>   
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, probably the select attribute of the copy-of element should be select="." instead of select="*", but that was not the issue here.

Comment: This will likely not output well-formed XML (multiple top-level elements), but that would be an issue in the original question's XSL too, if it worked.

Comment: That's because there are multiple top-level elements (as pointed out by JLRishe). Just embed the for-each element in your stylesheet in a root element.